# Check if folder with a specific size exists

Tags: powershell

From a executed  `Get-ChildItem` command i would like to check if a folder with a size greater then 1gb exist. For a specific reason gci command can not be executed directly with `Where-Object {$psiscontainer}`, filtering must be done after that gci executed.

Comment: You would need to do a recursive calculation of all the files and contained within the folder as well as all subfolders before you can tell what the size of the folder is.  Windows doesn't provide a method to get the full size directly.

Comment: In addition to @Robbert comment, check this link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/25/getting-directory-sizes-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: I already have a function to scan all folders. My question is how to check if a folder with a size 1gb exist. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** rearranged code a bit.

This should help, I used your idea of using `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, and modified the function to return all folders bigger than the provided `$minsize`

```
function Get-FolderBySize {  
   param (
        [string]$path,
        [Int32]$minSize # in GB
    )

    $folders = gci -Path $Path -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? {$_.PSisContainer -eq $true}
    $FileSystemObject = New-Object -ComObject  Scripting.FileSystemObject   

    foreach ($folder in $folders)
    { 
        $size = $FileSystemObject.GetFolder($folder.FullName).Size / 1GB

        if ($size -ge $minSize)
        {
            $size = "{0:N}" -f $size
            Write-host "Folder $($folder.Fullname) has a size of $size GB" 
            $folder
        }
    }
}
```